# How to set screenOrientation for phone and tablet

Tags: android

My manifest.xml as below:

```
    <activity
        android:name="packagename"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And onCreate in Activity as below:

```
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
        //Tablet
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }
    else {
        //Mobile
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

I set default SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR in manifest.xml.
And judge phone or tablet in onCreate.
But it may show LANDSCAPE at first, and then change to PORTRAIT on phone device.
I don't want to show LANDSCAPE at first.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defer the call to `setContentView()` until after the following:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if(manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
    //Tablet
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}
else {
    //Mobile
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
}

// Set content View
setContentView(R.layout.whatever);

// Or
setContentView(mContentView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your manifest.xml file.

```
<activity android:name=".activity"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Comment: But this still has same problem on tablet.

Comment: It may show PORTRAIT, and then change to LANDSCAPE on tablet.

Answer (score 1):

remove everyting related to Orientation you coded and then add this

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

to your activity.